# Dojo onCellDblClick function don't work

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I work with Dojo, using grid and when i double click on cell or column i got error `TypeError: this._click[0] is undefined`. So I look into code and see:

```
onCellDblClick: function(e){
        // summary:
        //      Event fired when a cell is double-clicked.
        // e: Event
        //      Decorated event object contains reference to grid, cell, and rowIndex
        console.log(this);
        if(dojo.isIE){
            this.edit.setEditCell(this._click[1].cell, this._click[1].rowIndex);
        }else if(this._click[0].rowIndex != this._click[1].rowIndex){
            this.edit.setEditCell(this._click[0].cell, this._click[0].rowIndex);
        }else{
            this.edit.setEditCell(e.cell, e.rowIndex);
        }
        this.onRowDblClick(e);
    },
```

Problem is that *_click* is empty array. I don't have any experience with dojo and dont know when get that data.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle showing an example of the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
on(GridNode, 'CellDblClick', lang.hitch(this, function () { ... });
```